# Not able to invite users to Google Classroom

Tags: php, api, curl, google-classroom

I am trying to invite a user to Google Classroom with the following PHP code:

```
$paramertos = array(
    "role" => "STUDENT", 
    "userId" => $mail, 
    "courseId" => $courseId
);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/invitations",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $paramertos,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "authorization: Bearer $access_token"
    )
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error:" . $err;
} else {
    $response = json_decode($response, true);
    var_dump($response);
}
```

The result is:

```
array(1) { 
    ["error"]=> array(3) {
        ["code"]=> int(400) 
        ["message"]=> string(37) "Request contains an invalid argument."
        ["status"]=> string(16) "INVALID_ARGUMENT" 
    }
 }
```

The $access_token, $mail, and $courseId are correct.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you do it through the website? Are you trying to use this for functionality or as just a fun coding challenge?

Comment: I need it for a integration to create courses an enroll users (both of them work), but I need to invite users where is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution serching in the [Google API client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) code. Not documentation found for invitations.

```
$service = new Google_Service_Classroom($client);

$googleInvitation = new Google_Service_Classroom_Invitation(
    array("role" => "STUDENT",
    "userId" => $mail,
    "courseId" => $courseId)
);
try{
    $invitationRes = $service->invitations->create($googleInvitation);
}catch(Exception $exception){
    echo $exception;
    die();
}
var_dump($invitationRes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Error 400 meaning you've created a bad request.

> **INVALID_ARGUMENT** if the query argument is malformed.

For easier coding, you can use [Google API client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client). Here is a sample code to help you understand more about Google PHP client library (Unfortunately, I don't have any code sample for creating an invite).

```
$courseId = '123456';
$teacherEmail = 'alice@example.edu';
$teacher = new Google_Service_Classroom_Teacher(array(
  'userId' => $teacherEmail
));
try {
  $teacher = $service->courses_teachers->create($courseId, $teacher);
  printf("User '%s' was added as a teacher to the course with ID '%s'.\n",
      $teacher->profile->name->fullName, $courseId);
} catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
  if ($e->getCode() == 409) {
    printf("User '%s' is already a member of this course.\n", $teacherEmail);
  } else {
    throw $e;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I use the Google API client library for get, list, update, create courses and enroll users to the course. For delete course, get the user profile and create an invitation I can not use the library. (Delete course and get the user profile works)